# Wordpress/Woo add headers BCC on custom email template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have gift cards plugin that is sending a custom email template to the user. How do I manipulate that email header in my functions.php file and add a BCC based on a custom order meta? That order meta has an email address in the value.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'order_completed_email_add_bcc', 9999, 15 );    
function order_completed_email_add_bcc( $headers, $email, $order ) {
        if ( 'pw_gift_card' == $email ) {
            $bcc = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'my_custom_order_meta', true );
            $headers .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."" . "\r\n";
        }
        return $headers;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seem to be alright although it needs improvement. You have 3 arguments and not 15. Also for brevity, use `$order->get_meta()` instead of `get_post_meta()`.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'order_completed_email_add_bcc', 9999, 3 );    
function order_completed_email_add_bcc( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {
    if ( 'pw_gift_card' == $email_id && $bcc = $order->get_meta('my_custom_order_meta')) {
        $headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $bcc . '\r\n';
    }
    return $headers;
}
```